# How do refresh RecyclerView of one fragment by button click in another fragment

Tags: android

I have two fragments in an activity.
RecordFragment records audio, RecordingsFragment displays all the record audio.
My problem is how do I refresh RecyclerView of RecordingsFragment after I click stop button in RecordFragment.

[RecordFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgL1t.png)

[RecordingsFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVt8Y.png)

This is code for adapter. Utils.getListOfNames() retrives list of files from storage.

```
mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
mAdapter = new RecordingsListAdapter(Utils.getListOfNames(), getContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
```

This is the onClick of stopButton

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Stop clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
mediaRecorder.stop();
startButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Use interface for call back

Comment: what did you write so far ? I hope you are not using a static list

Comment: Try to improve your question, check [ask]. Add the code you are using or more details to have a more precise solution.

Comment: There you go https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 1):

you can check following links

[How to update the ListView of a Fragment from another Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386109/how-to-update-the-listview-of-a-fragment-from-another-fragment).
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know about Broadcast Receivers, if not then read here[Android Broadcast Receivers](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) and for [detail practical implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/2106820) and use local broadcast receivers to do this.